# error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from long to int

Tags: java

I am trying to resolve this error.
The below code is an implementation of ugly numbers.

```
    /* Function to get the nth ugly number*/
    long getNthUglyNo(int n) {
        // code here
        long[] ugly=new long[n];
        long next_2=2,next_3=3,next_5=5;
        long i1=0,i2=0,i3=0;
        long next=1;
        ugly[0]=1;
        for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
        {
            next=Math.min(next_2,Math.min(next_3,next_5));
            ugly[i]=next;
            if(next==next_2)
            {
                i1++;
                next_2=ugly[i1]*2;
            }
            if(next==next_3)
            {
                i2++;
                next_3=ugly[i2]*3;
            }
            if(next==next_5)
            {
                i3++;
                next_5=ugly[i3]*5;
            }
        }
        return next;
    }
}
```

error I am getting -->
prog.java:36: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from long to int

```
            next_2=ugly[i1]*2;

                        ^
```

prog.java:41: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from long to int

```
            next_3=ugly[i2]*3;
                        ^
```

prog.java:46: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from long to int

```
            next_5=ugly[i3]*5;
```

I am not able to resolve this. I don't know what is wrong with my code.

Comment: Array index requires `int` data type and you passed a value of type `long` to it that's why the compiler is unhappy. Change type of `i1`, `i2` and `i3` to `int`,

Comment: That's because a long is 64 bits and an int is 32 bits. Try to typecast it to `(int)` if you are okay by losing some digits

Answer (score 2):

On Java array, they need an integer as array position to get value in it. Those errors appear because your `i1`, `i2`, and `i3` variable is a `Long` data type. To get rid of those errors, you must convert the variable to be an integer type.

You can use:

```java
int position = Integer.parseInt(i1);
next_2 = ugly[position]*2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Array index requires int. You are passing int variables i1, i2 etc. Just change the Array to ArrayList. It will work without any manual casting of int from long.